# Vue.js: Dynamically render html in child component's slot

Tags: html, vue.js, text, render

In my vue.js application, I am trying to render the `html` content dynamically in child component's slot. If I enter the text only then there is no issue, it works with fine.

Here is my code:

ChildComponent.vue

```js
<template>
    <div :class="type" class="message" v-if="type">
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    ...
    props: ['type'],
    ...
}
</script>
```

ParentComponent.vue

```js
<script>
import Alert from '@/Alert';

export default {
    components: {
        Alert,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            ...
            alert: {
                error: '',
                message: '',
            }
        };
    },
    created () {
        this._onLoad()
    },
    methods: {
        _onLoad() {
            axios.get(`api.call.here`).then((res) => {
                ...
            }).catch(error => {
                this.alert.error = error.type;
                this.alert.message = `<p>message here</p>`; // from response
            });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Comment: This is what v-html is for. It's unsafe, so whether this is acceptable really depends on what api it is and the possibility that it provides malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do can be achieved with `v-html`. You can use it while calling your `ChildComponent.vue`. This is a small example for your case:

```
<Alert>
   <span v-html="alert.message"></span>
</Alert>
```